# Silverlight - How to implement this functionality? Nice feature

Tags: silverlight

I don't know what this is called in SL, but I would like to replicate this functionality.  If you go to this site: http://www.mscui.com/PatientJourneyDemonstrator/PrimaryCareAdmin.htm and click on the "Show Details" button located on the top, right-hand corder of the screen.  When you click on this, there should be a "Scene Details" button-like feature on the right side.  When you click on this, this is what I would like to implement.  Can someone direct me please? Either to an online article, etc...

Comment: You could describe what the feature you're after does, looks like, ...

Comment: I believe the person is looking for the "guide" overlay that dims the underlying page and offers explanations for all of the controls.

Comment: At noted, all I want is how the "Scene Details" functionality works, i.e. from going from a simple-looking button, to a small panel with some nice expandability.

Comment: As soon as someone can figure out what "this" means, can we please edit the title to be more accurate? I don't even have Silverlight installed, but I don't want this title showing up in the questions page like "How to do this?".

Comment: Please do not use this UI as an example. It's horrible in too many ways to describe.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not precisely sure what feature of the site you'r referring to (I'm blind so the description doesn't make much sense to me). However, two useful links - some of the MSCUI source code is available on Codeplex http://mscui.codeplex.com. Also, the Silverlight developer/designer on this project created Blacklight http://blacklight.codeplex.com which includes visual assets to use with Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know the specifics of the implementation, as far as I can guess, this is done by having a second Grid that follows the Grid for the page. Then, simply change the visiblity on the "guide" grid when the button toggles.

I believe that is simple, although it'll require you to work to figure out the positioning of the underlying page - but it's more flexible. With Blend it'll be easy.

Alternatively you could have a ton of additional UI elements on the page next to their respective controls, and either Tag or name them in a way that you can iterate over them to control visibility and interaction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about a the grey overlay with a modal window on top. I think the best way to do that in Silverlight 3 is with [the ChildWindow control](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%204).